# Output Formatting Python 3.2

Tags: formatting, python-3.x

I have a question relating to the output of a program.

```
 def writeOutput():
    output.write(str(gallons) + '\n')
    output.write(str(usage) + '\n')
    output.write(str(sewer) + '\n')
    output.write(str(tax) + '\n')
    output.write(str(total) + '\n')
    output.write('_______________________' + '\n')
```

This is my write to file function. 
Does anybody know where I can look to find out how to write 123.45 as "123 dollars 45 cents" with dollars and cents spelled out like that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `amount` stored as a `float`(*), you can use the `%` formatting operator as follows:

```
"%d dollars %d cents" % (int(amount), int(amount * 100 % 100))
```

or

```
dollars = int(amount)
"%d dollars %d cents" % (dollars, int((amount - dollars) * 100))
```

(*) Which you should never do in a real financial app, since floating point is prone to rounding errors; use the `Decimal` module instead.

Comment: I keep getting the following type error      File "C:\Python32\FinalProject\main.py", line 38, in main
        outputWater = str("d dollars %d cents" %(charges, (charges * 100 % 100)))
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'module' and 'int'
>>>

Comment: and I can't quite get the hang of these comments...  and line breaks :(

Comment: @Alli, have you included a module called `charges`? It's not an error in my code; try it on the Python prompt.

Comment: I have included a module named charges, yes.  Guess I should have thought of that...  I will update my variable names and try again.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This would work:

```
>>> amount = 123.45
>>> '{} dollars {:.0f} cents'.format(int(amount), (amount - int(amount)) * 100)
'123 dollars 45 cents'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 (all 3.x?) for "simple" floats you can write:

```
'{} dollars {} cents'.format( *str(amount).split('.') )
```

Output:

```
'123 dollars 45 cents'
```

*Apparently, str() will screw float numbers like `1.0000000001e-15`*